# Crash in self.view after constructor on iOS 8.1 and 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to do a simple SpriteKit action - adding a view to a scene:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LevelsEditorStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.levelsEditor = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LevelsEditorId"];
[self.scene.view addSubview:self.levelsEditor.view];
```

On iOS 8.0 and 8.3 is working fine and on iOS 8.1 and 8.2 I'm getting the following error:

```
SPBingo[75304:80943666] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextSelectionView name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I realised that this crash caused by the UITextField. 
Once I'm getting rid of it, replacing the UITextField with some UITextView ( not ideal but whatever) The view is loading but when I try to click on a UITextView it crashed. The other Input views work (switches, dataPicker, tableView etc.)

After a deep dive into it I figured out that the problem occur in the contractor already. When I put breakpoint on the the second line in the following code :

```
-(instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}
```

and try to print "self.view" I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
```

The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
ODD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. it is an internal bug by Apple which create in 8.1 and fixed in 8.3.
The solution is avoid using the UITextView contractor "initWithFrame" and use the following one:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: frame textContainer: textContainer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the view until after the "viewDidLoad:" method signature is called, otherwise it attempts to create the view before all the prerequisites are in place.

Make sure to call self.view from "viewDidLoad:", "viewWillAppear:" or "viewDidAppear:" when it has properly been setup.

Comment: That's a good tip - it's not the problem though.
Moreover, I know what you're saying - but I'm trying to print self.view after the constructor - in a normal situation the [self viewSisLoad] would be invoked and it will print the new view. If you print _view it will be nil.